# Dynamically use SelectToUISlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic

My current project creates user forms dynamically from a database.  One of the tables defines what type of input a question should be formatted for the user.  I am having difficulties getting a slider UI element working with this paradigm.  SelectToUISlider, originally designed by the Filament Group, seems to be a good fit; however, I have been unsuccessful calling the UDF on the generic SELECT element from JQuery when there are more than one on a page.

If there is only a single SELECT I have no issues.  If I hard-code the ID tag to be selected I have no issues.  But getting it to use the ^= or |= selector has been completely unsuccessful.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$("select[id^='slider']").selectToUISlider();

http://jsfiddle.net/wolfphantom/zuvtpnLg/1/
```

Comment: As I continue my research into an answer myself I wonder if there is a means to use a JQuery factory to solve my dynamic issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the JsFiddle example you have provided it is working, isn't it?

So it seems you have a problem related to the dynamic select that gets populated at run-time after a certain operation...

So If you want to initiate the selectToUISlider on a single strip you can do is,

```
$(document).find("select[id^='slider']").selectToUISlider();
```

And i have created a [Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuvtpnLg/2/) that includes a dynamic select being added in run-time.

But you want to implement selectToUISlider for each and every select individually, then why not run the loop on those element and initialize it individually.

```
$("select[id^='slider']").each(function(){
        $(this).selectToUISlider();
});
```

So, the downfall, however will be, it will not work on dynamic elements, So you need to initialize those after the element is added to the DOM.

And here is the [Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuvtpnLg/3/) for it.

P.S

I don't have a prior knowledge of the plugin, But I hope it will work for you.

Regards.

Comment: The 2nd JSFiddle is something I attempted before, but my lack of experience with JQuery meant I didn't get the results.  Thank you so much for the help.  I found another solution I am going to use for now, but it is good to know that I was looking at it correctly. Now I just need to practice more JQuery.